# NASM, where is my DIV remainder?

Tags: nasm

I've tried googling to find where the remainder goes in NASM's div. For 8-bit division it looks like the quotient is in al and the remainder in al. But I've also seen people say it will be in dl. At this point, I'm pretty confused. In my code below I'm trying to print out the quotient and the remainder to check my work before I move on. I can't seem to get the remainder correctly. (Base is the divisor)

```
asciiout: db "%c %c", 10, 0

....
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor edx, edx
mov al, [Num]
mov bl, [Base]
div bl

add al, '0'
mov [Quotient], al
add ah, '0'
mov [Remainder], ah

push edx
push eax
push asciiout
call printf
add esp, 12
```

In case you skipped the above paragraph, where is my remainder going? Do I have to do separate mod division?

Comment: i think it divides the whole AX by BL. Your code looks correct to me, note that you are using: char Quotient, char Remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

> `DIV r/m8    Unsigned divide AX by r/m8, with result
>   stored in AL ←Quotient, AH ← Remainder.`

TL;DR: The remainder goes into `AH` in your case.

<strike>Note that the dividend is `AX` (16-bit), so you should clear `AH` prior to the division in case you're only using 8-bit dividends.</strike> <sup>(You're already doing this with the `xor eax,eax`)</sup>

Comment: I made some modifications to what I'm printing and got 'K'. So i clearly need to step through with gdb, but getting results is better than no results. Thanks for the help.